# With Xcode 6.2 Update, Find in Workspace Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-6.2

After updating Xcode to 6.2 (6C131e), doing "Find in Workspace" crashes with "UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Could not find class named UIImage". I tried "Clean Build Folder" to no avail. Are there other Xcode caches or indexes that I should try to reset?

```
Process:               Xcode [21278]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.2 (6776)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6776000000000000~11
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       811890240
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [21278]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-03-15 19:53:43.364 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C1510)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        539D7F12-9E6C-9CC5-F6D9-1FDBD16DF85D

Sleep/Wake UUID:       B9E7A3DF-5CB3-4194-82BA-4445905D6A2D

Time Awake Since Boot: 120000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       340 seconds

Crashed Thread:        21  Dispatch queue: IDEBatchFindReplace_ConcurrentQueue :: NSOperation 0x7fdb7f20c550 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6C131e
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Could not find class named UIImage
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff94143654 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x0000000106601764 DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00007fff9546176e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3  0x00007fff9414344a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4  0x00007fff928273a9 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] (in Foundation)
  5  0x000000010d4bdf21 -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] (in IBFoundation)
  6  0x000000010d53ac3e +[IBUserDefinedRuntimeAttribute decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBFoundation)
  7  0x000000010d4bdf47 -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] (in IBFoundation)
  8  0x000000010d4b93a0 -[NSDictionary(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) initWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBFoundation)
  9  0x000000010d4b8411 +[NSObject(IBBinaryArchivingAdditions) decodeWithBinaryUnarchiver:] (in IBFoundation)
 10  0x000000010d4bdf47 -[IBBinaryUnarchiver decodeObject] (in IBFoundation)
 11  0x000000010d4bd017 +[IBBinaryUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:context:minArchiveVersion:] (in IBFoundation)
 12  0x00000001112c2aeb -[IBAttributeSearchLocation initWithPropertyList:owner:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x00000001113faff8 -[IBSearchableAttributeDescription initWithPropertyList:owner:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x00000001113fa3eb __64-[IBDocumentMemberSearchDescription initWithPropertyList:owner:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15  0x000000010d4c8be9 IBArrayByMappingCollectionWithBehavior (in IBFoundation)
 16  0x00000001113fa2f6 -[IBDocumentMemberSearchDescription initWithPropertyList:owner:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x00000001113f99cc __58-[IBDocumentSearchDescription initWithPropertyList:owner:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x000000010d4c8be9 IBArrayByMappingCollectionWithBehavior (in IBFoundation)
 19  0x00000001113f9923 -[IBDocumentSearchDescription initWithPropertyList:owner:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x000000011161240e -[IBTextIndexDataProvider findableForFilePath:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21  0x00000001070f5abf -[IDETextIndex _computeFindableForFilePath:withDataProvider:] (in IDEFoundation)
 22  0x00000001070f7e27 -[IDETextIndexTextFindableWrapper findStringMatchingDescriptor:backwards:from:to:] (in IDEFoundation)
 23  0x00000001064c703a -[DVTTextFinder _findNext] (in DVTFoundation)
 24  0x00000001064c6f36 -[DVTTextFinder findBeforeDate:] (in DVTFoundation)
 25  0x0000000107adb62a -[IDEBatchDocumentFindable performFind] (in IDEKit)
 26  0x00007fff9273c32c -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 27  0x00007fff9273bf33 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 28  0x00007fff9670dc13 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 29  0x00007fff96711365 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 30  0x00007fff96712ecc _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 31  0x00007fff967106b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 32  0x00007fff9671efe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 33  0x00007fff90950637 _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 34  0x00007fff9094e40d start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
```

Comment: There are caches in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, but deleting them does not work :(

Comment: We can confirm it in our team, happens for everyone with the same project.
Only happens when using a Cocoapod-Workspace.

Comment: PS: Also only happens when the search finds an instance inside a storyboard. Makes sense because the crash-report mentions "IDEInterfaceBuilderKit".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a bug in xcode, happens when you search for strings in Xcode 6.2 and the search finds instances in a storyboard that is part of a Workspace.

What fixed it in our case was to open, save & close all storyboards.

Comment: This solution also worked for me on a XIB-only project (no storyboards). Opened all XIBs, and no more crashing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently. Just open all storyboards in the app. It should work afterwards.